# Why user's iCloud Drive need to turn on for CloudKit based app uses only public container?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, icloud-drive

To be able to fetch user record ID in app uses only public container, there is more requirements from my experience:

1. user should be logged in to iCloud
2. iCloud Drive should be turned on for app
3. be online

Why second condition is required?

Comment: Did you ever find an explanation for this? I'm bumping into the same issue as well.

Comment: This issue is so confusing. Apple never gives an explanation. They don't even describe it in the docs.